# Проблема выведения данных на экран

Tags: arduino

```
  void printbuf(){
  int i;
  int a=0;  
  //Пока не кончилась длина буфера повторяем цикл
  for (i = 0; i < buflen; i++)
  {
    //Если встретили первую / значит сейчас пойдет температура
    if ((char) buf[i]=='/'){
      if (a==0){ 
        display.setCursor(0,0);
        display.print("Temperature");
        a++;
      }
      // Иначе влажность
      else {
        display.setCursor(0, 10);
        display.print("Humidity");
       }
    }
    else
    {
      // Если / нет выводим данные
      display.print((char)buf[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Проблема в том, что display.print((char)buf[i]); ничего не выводит на экран.

Answer (score 0):

Есть встроенная библиотека - liquidCrystal для работы с жк-дисплеями.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>  
LiquidCrystal lcd(распиновка);  
lcd.begin(16, 2);  
lcd.print("Hello world!");
```

Вот такой вот синтаксис. Подробнее - погугли.

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня OLED-дисплей. И библиотека используется adafruit-овская. Изначальный код написан для "LiquidCrystal" библиотеки, а я хочу осуществить всё это на OLED экране.

Comment: Пришлите пожалуйста модель своего экрана.